# .Net Visio Control don't show the vsd File

Tags: vb.net, visio

i use the Visio WinForm OCX in my programm and i wan't to open a .vsd file.

i use the following code to open a File

```
vis_Draw.Focus()
vis_Draw.Document.Application.Documents.OpenEx(strFile, CShort(Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked))
```

my problem is, the visio control don't show the open

Comment: This doesn't look like a winforms control. It looks like an old vb6 control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the control's "Src" property to open a document in an existing VisOcx instance:

```
vis_Draw.Src = strFile
```